# randomizing timestamp without timezone in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there any way to randomize a timestamp without timezone with an interval of within 1hour?
For example:

```
event_start = '2019-10-31 13:00:00'
event_end = '2019-10-31 14:00:00'
```

but can also be

```
event_start = '2019-10-31 13:00:00'
event_end = '2019-10-31 13:40:59'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add a random number of minutes to your timestamp:

```
timestamp '2019-10-31 13:00:00' + make_interval(mins => (random() * 59)::int)
```

Comment: do you mean to say '2019-10-31 13:00:00' + make_interval(mins => (random() * 59)::int)? Because what i need is the in between or the 1hr to be exact between the 13:00:00 and the 14:00:00

Comment: @a_hose_with_no_name may i also ask on how to randomize timestamp w/o timezone?

Comment: @ElijahLeis: that **is** a timestamp without time zone. But the handling would be identical for both datatypes.

Comment: i meant instead of typing the value '2019-10-31 13:00:00'. How can I randomize the value instead

Comment: Which value? You can replace that with a column obviously

Comment: I meant the event_start column. How can i insert random values for the date and the time?